# Fail2ban Custom Port

Tags: ubuntu, security, ssh, debian, fail2ban

I have a rule like this in my jail.local file:

```
[ssh-ddos]

enabled = true
port    = ssh,sftp
filter  = sshd-ddos
logpath  = /var/log/messages
maxretry = 4
```

If I want to use a custom port for SSH, does Fail2ban automatically infer it from my sshd_config file or should I specify the port numerically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify the custom port in the `[ssh]` section, something like this:

```
[ssh]
port=2317
```

Comment: Thanks, wanted to double check. Thought it might read the sshd_config (that'd be sweet).

Comment: It reads /etc/services for standard port names.

Comment: This is completely valid while I have a custom sshd.xml file under /etc/firewalld/services with the custom port of sshd. firewalld and selinux are completely ok with my setup; but "fail2ban fails 2 ban" --Thanks :)